# Ayin hora - evil eye

Tags: children-parenting, pictures, ayin-hara-evil-eye

I have observed a Phenomenon among older Eurpoean Jewry ( i.e. Yiddishe mammes and bubbes) not to display pictures of their children or grandchildren ( eineklach) in open areas for fear of ayin hora.

[And if they do show someone the pictures ( when they can't hold themselves back), there is a custom that the other person spits as if to ward off the ayin hora, well not really spit but they make the tzu tzu noise as if they are]

Does anyone know of a source for this and how far does it extend?

Comment: Well it cant go back further than the early eighteen hundreds when cameras were invented.

Comment: @user6591, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portrait_painting

Comment: Uh thanks fir the link. Wouldna figured out what a portrait meant otherwise ;) But when for instance the Chazon Ish tried not to allow having pictures taken of him saying 'people who take pictures don't understand what a tzelem elokim is' is only really possible with cameras. The people who sat for hours on end for a portrait painting would probably not turn around and shun the painting.